# Unable to upload upadated version of expnasion file in google play store?

Tags: android, apk, expansion

I am developing an application with expansion feature.
First time I uploaded an apk with expansion file successfully.But i want to upload next version of apk with updated expansion file version.But its disable dropdown to upload the expansion file.And enabled only patch version uploaded.

Example:-

```
      First Time :-

        Apk:- firstdemov1.apk

        Expansion File:- main.1.com.apps.firstdemo.obb.zip

      Second Time :-

        Apk:- firstdemov2.apk

        Expansion File:- main.2.com.apps.firstdemo.obb.zip
```

If anyone have idea please reply.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's because your apk must have the same name as before.
Just increase the versionCode in your manifest, and the versionName as-well if you want to (the last one is optional).